# Multiple audio files, one Sound object?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5

Is it possible to play multiple sound files using a single sound object? (I've looked into this back when I was using Flash CS3, but I want to know if anything has changed.)

(I'm trying to make a playlist which will play music in the background of my SWF movie and then have a frame where users can change the song and the volume.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one persistent **Sound** - every time you need to reload a new audio file into the **Sound**, just do

```
mySound = new Sound(myURLRequest);
```

Then reattach to **SoundChannel**, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible to create a playlist as you describe.
I'm not sure exactly what you mean by the first part (using a single sound object).

The volume control will be done on the SoundChannel object, not the Sound, so it shouldn't matter if they are one Sound object or many.

Sorry if that doesn't answer your question.